# d: \ learning \ vbs \ backup3.vbs (32, 1) Runtime Error Microsoft VBScript: Path not found

Tags: vbscript

When I am running script, I am getting error, I can not understand why.
The error is:

> d:\learning\vbs\backup3.vbs (32, 1)
> Runtime Error Microsoft VBScript: Path not found.

Error in this string: `Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(str)`

My code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO
Dim objShell
Dim objFolder
Dim sourceDir
Dim destDir
Dim rar
Dim n
sourceDir = "d:\learning\vbs\TBack"
destDir = "\\LILO\Users\monorels\Music\Backup"
rar = "d:\learning\vbs\Rar.exe"
n = 3

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objShell.Run """rar"" a -agYYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS " & destDir & " " & sourceDir
search_delete "\\LILO\Users\monorels\Music\Backup", n

Sub search_delete(str, n)
    Dim strOldestFile, dtmOldestDate
    Dim count
    Dim intFolderSize
    Dim objFolder
    Dim colFiles
    Dim strFile
    Dim delFile
    Dim fso

    strOldestFile = ""
    dtmOldestDate = Now
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(str)
    Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

    Do
        count = 0
        For Each objFile In colFiles
            count = count + 1
            strFile = objFile.Path
            dtmFileDate = objFile.DateCreated
            If dtmFileDate < dtmOldestDate Then
                dtmOldestDate = dtmFileDate
                strOldestFile = strFile
            End If
        Next
            objFSO.DeleteFile (strOldestFile)
    Loop Until count > n
End Sub
```

Help me, please.

Comment: Isn't the error descriptive enough? The path on the `str` variable isn't a valid folder path.

Comment: and such a valid?       "d:\learning\vbs\Backup"   It does not work

Comment: That's not the path it's complaining about. The path it can't access is: `"\\LILO\Users\monorels\Music\Backup"`.

Comment: This path is giving you issues: `\\LILO\Users\monorels\Music\Backup` I am not sure if the fso needs a slash on the end of the path or not or if the path simply doesn't exist. Hold windows key and press `r` then paste that path in and hit enter, does it open the location?

Comment: @DanDonoghue A trailing backslash is not required.